# Remove quotes from Ansible variable output

Tags: automation, yaml, ansible, jinja2, configuration-management

I'm using this task to add a line to a file:

```
lineinfile: "dest={{ ansible_env.HOME }}/{{ deploy_dir }}/config/deploy/{{ stage_name }}.rb
              insertbefore='# role-based syntax'
              line='server "'{{ ip_addr }}'", user: "'{{ user_name }}'", roles: %w{'{{ role }}'}'"
```

Which adds this line:

```
server '172.16.8.11', user: 'vagrant', roles: %w{'api'}
```

But I don't want the quotes around `api`. Instead I want this output:

```
server '172.16.8.11', user: 'vagrant', roles: %w{api}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Actually the quotes do not come from the variable, but are right there in your string:

```
%w{'{{ role }}'}
```

Now the solution is little bit tricky though. Because you can not simply remove the quotes like that:

```
%w{{{ role }}}
```

This would result into a parse error, since `{{` starts an expression...

The solution is to write the outer parentheses, which are meant to be in the string, as an expression themselves.

So to output `{` you would instead write `{{'{'}}` and instead of `}` you would write `{{'}'}}`. Does that make sense? You're instructing the template engine (Jinja2) to output the parentheses to avoid the parsing error:

```
%w{{'{'}}{{ role }}{{'}'}}
```

But since `role` is an expression already, you just also can group it together into one single expression:

```
%w{{ '{'+role+'}' }}
```

Your whole task would then read like this:

```
- lineinfile:
    dest: "{{ ansible_env.HOME }}/{{ deploy_dir }}/config/deploy/{{ stage_name }}.rb"
    insertbefore: "# role-based syntax"
    line: "server '{{ ip_addr }}', user: '{{ user_name }}', roles: %w{{ '{'+role+'}' }}"
```

<sup>This also is converted into proper YAML syntax because this quoted k=v format is just really hard to read. :)</sup>